# Updated world map for R "maps" package?

Tags: r, maps, geospatial

```
library(maps)
1> map.where(database="world",29.392089,53.592505)
[1] "USSR"
```

does anyone know how I can get an updated world map database to drive this function in the maps package?  I need country names only for now, not detailed sub-national administrative information such as is available in at gadm.org.

Comment: there's probably a way to do an equivalent task with the `rworldmap` package, but I can't figure it out right now ...

Comment: You mean something like http://geocommons.com/overlays/33578 ?

Comment: maps and mapdata are really out of date and unclean topologically too, it's easy to get broken shapes out of it - I would avoid it for anything but the roughest of background maps. Sometimes though you will have to find your own source, rgdal is the best bet for reading.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `wrld_simpl` in the `maptools` package.

```
require(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl)

## or subset based on the name
plot(wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$NAME == "Russia", ])
## explore other attributes
summary(wrld_simpl)
```

I don't know how up to date it is, but `?wrld_simpl` describes the source so you might find good stuff following links. Other packages that rely on `sp` will also be worth exploring for data.

Otherwise, there was the Rgshhs package, though I'm not sure that's still available. It came with fair detail but you can download more if you need it. It's a bit complicated, the original data is here: http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/gshhs.html

You can also read in data from vector formats (like MIF or SHP or PostGIS) using `rgdal` if you have your own data, or similar read functions in `maptools` for shapefile only.

Example to query the objects using points:

```
require(sp)
require(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
pts <- SpatialPoints(cbind(c(29.392089,147), c(53.592505, -35)), CRS(proj4string(wrld_simpl)))

over(pts, wrld_simpl)$NAME
```

For an introduction to these and other functions in `sp` see vignette("sp").

Also try the `geonames` package for more general querying of geographic names.

Comment: thanks, but how do I query those datasets using something like `map.where(database="wrld_simpl",29.392089,53.592505)`.  Its not working.  I don't need to make any visual maps, I just need to be able to give coordinates and get country names.

Comment: ok, added an example - I missed that part in your question and was only thinking about the actual map. maps::map.where is not going to help you.