# Historic Maps in R

Tags: r, maps, spatial, shapefile

Being concerned with a spatial data analysis with data ranging from 1950 to 2016 I would like to plot some nice features in a world map in R. However, as the political landscape has changed with time, the actual implementations (e.g. the R package rworldmap) give the recent countries (Although, not long ago that was not true for all packages: [Updated world map for R "maps" package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757793/updated-world-map-for-r-maps-package)).

Hence my question is, whether there is some package with historic maps or otherwise some online-source for shapefiles or polygons for worldmaps, beginning in 1950.

Comment: answer below (which may be deleted) suggests  http://www.aag.org/cs/projects_and_programs/historical_gis_clearinghouse/hgis_projects_programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the package [cshapes](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/cshapes/) from CRAN:

> R Package for CShapes, a GIS dataset of country boundaries
>   (1946-2015). Includes functions for data extraction and the
>   computation of weights matrices.

It lets you extract a dataset for a chosen time, which you can then also use with any mapping tool you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much, the cshapes package is just amazing!